# How can I verify email addresses?

Tags: 8, users, emails

Here is the workflow

1. Users register with a valid email and a password
2. Drupal automatically sends an email to the new registered user
3. The email contains a link to verify the email
4. The email verification is performed

This is similar to email addition and verification of http://drupal.org. I can't find any module for that purpose. Some patches are available on https://www.drupal.org/node/115801. Any way?

Answer (score 2):

That sounds like the core behaviour to: "*Require email verification when a visitor creates an account*"

[image: Drupal 8 account settings]

However, the password will be selected after clicking the email verification link, to activate the account.